# Stop custom UITableviewCell from reducing content

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm building a custom cell, i've layers to add shadow to, and other stuff, but the cell are loaded fine then whenever scrolled it started to cascade in a weird way, i checked my constraints and it's totally fine, tried couple of `setlayoutifneeded`, but still nothing.

Here are images for both cases:

**Normal:**

[image: normal:]

**Cropped:**

[image: cropped]

How to fix this?

Comment: same thing happens when cell selected too

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing - that only starts after scrolling - is often related to prepareForReuse:. Are you overloading that?

When the cell is configured it can be being *re-configured*. Any constraints you had set in there from a prior config are *still* in there, setting the height etc.

You can remove old constraints in prepareForReuse.

Comment: I've just started implementing prepareForReuse, what do you think should i reset or add? i tried to reset display or layout and it didn't work either